# How to connect my new .net domain to node.js server IP

Tags: domain-name-system, node.js, dns-hosting

I have port forwarded my IP and port. Everything works great and I can connect to my node.js server at *mypublicip:1337* from another device on another network.

So, I purchased a domain and now I need to know how to connect it to that certain IP and port. When I navigate to my website link, I want to see the same as I would see at *mypublicip:1337*.

Answer (score 1):

Create in Your domain A record pointing to *mypublicip* and You can access server by name http://mydomainname:1337